# Nuxt JS LocalStorage in Universal mode not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm working on a Nuxt JS application which utilises LocalStorage. When compiling in `SPA` mode it functions correctly, however I need to switch my project to `universal` mode to get my SEO meta titles and descriptions to work when generating my project, after switching I get an error on a few pages which utilise LocalStorage:

```
localStorage is not defined
```

Has anyone got any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Ofc it dont work, localstorage exist only on client in browser, and obv not in node

Comment: what about `window.localStorage`? Show some of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have localStorage because there is no such thing in Node.js environment. You also don't have `window` and `document` objects.

https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/universal.html#access-to-platform-specific-apis

Nuxt.js uses Vue SSR under the hood.

However, you still have a store (Vuex). And it will be synchronized between node and browser.

Answer (score 0):

I needed data to persist between sessions for GDPR. You can use the mounted life cycle event and wait for window.localStorage to be available. Then assign it to a data property and add a v-if in a wrapper tag so the page doesn't start rendering before localeStorage is available. I'm doing this with a static nuxt build:

```
<div v-if="localStorageReady">
    Awesome stuff here...
</div>

data() {
  return {
    localStorageReady: false,
  }
},

mounted() {
  if (window.localStorage) {
    this.localStorageReady = true
  }
}
```